# withColumn does not return negative value

Tags: azure-databricks

I am trying to add a column to a dataframe using withColumn. if the reported date or acknoledgement date is null it should return -1 otherwise it should return the difference.
I write dataframe to a csv. It adds a new column to the csv, with the date difference as mentioned in otherwise, but does not return -1 if either of the date values is null. the CSV file has blank value for the when clause. What am I doing wrong?

```
val df_asbreportssv2 = df_asbreportssv1.withColumn(("AckOverdueby"), when(((df_asbreportssv1("nh_reporteddate").isNull)||(df_asbreportssv1("nh_acknowledgementdate").isNull) == "true"), -1 ).otherwise( datediff((df_asbreportssv1("nh_acknowledgementdate")),(df_asbreportssv1("nh_reporteddate")))))

val TempFilePath = "adl://dldataplatformdev1.azuredatalakestore.net/DDS_Learn/DDS_ASB/temp"
df_asbreportssv2.write
                          .mode("overwrite")
                          .format("csv")
                          .option("header", "true")
                          .save(TempFilePath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of code is not working properly as expected and it needs some refinement as follows.

```
val df_asbreportssv2 = df_asbreportssv1.withColumn(("AckOverdueby"), when((df_asbreportssv1("nh_reporteddate").isNull) || (df_asbreportssv1("nh_acknowledgementdate").isNull), -1 ).otherwise( datediff((df_asbreportssv1("nh_acknowledgementdate")),(df_asbreportssv1("nh_reporteddate")))))
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yeah!! Can you mark the answer as useful so that it could be helpful for others :)

Comment: @user13033419 Since the answer was helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.